# Compiler generated function class in Scala

Tags: scala, function, compiler-construction

I understand that when I do this:

```
val sum = (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b
```

Scala compiler turns it into this:

```
val sum = new Function2[Int, Int, Int] {
 def apply(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
}
```

So Function2 is a class made for Int based operations.We use [] to convey that operations in this class involves(input,output,body) only Int.
Isn't only one Int entry in [] sufficient to convey this. But we have 3 Int entries in [].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in `Function2` says that it is "made for Int based operations".

`Function2[X, Y, Z]` is a class for generic functions that that take two inputs of type `X` and `Y` and return a `Z`.

Specifying a single `Int` is obviously not sufficient, because `Function2` requires exactly *three* type parameters.

How would you otherwise be able to tell a difference between a

```
Function2[Int, Int, Int]
```

and a

```
Function2[Int, Double, String]
```

as for example in

```
val sum = (a: Int, b: Double) => a + " -> " + b
```

which is syntactic sugar for

```
val sum = new Function2[Int, Double, String] {
  def apply(a: Int, b: Double) = a + " -> " + b
}
```

?

---

If you often use `Function2[T, T, T]` for the same type `T`, you can define a type alias:

```
type BinOp[T] = Function2[T, T, T]
```

or shorter:

```
type BinOp[T] = (T, T) => T
```

Comment: Suppose Function2 has another method, which takes type X and return type Y. What form would [] take to represent these 2 operations?

Comment: @Mandroid The supposition is impossible. [Function2](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Function2.html) has only one `apply` method that takes exactly two parameters. And it will never change, because such a change would break absolutely everything in the entire Scala universe. If you want a function that takes type X and returns Y, there is [`Function1[X, Y]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Function1.html) for that.

Comment: And of course you can write your own trait which has both methods, just not change `Function2`.